# php fileinfo extension vulnerability

Tags: php, security, fileinfo

My shared hosting service is saying that they not turning on fileinfo because of security vulnerability. Can anybody explain me what kind of security issues are there in the fileinfo extension?

Comment: This question is better suited for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) Quote from [cevdetails.com](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-4636/) `The mget function in libmagic/softmagic.c in the Fileinfo component in PHP 5.4.x before 5.4.16 allows remote attackers to cause a denial of service (invalid pointer dereference and application crash) via an MP3 file that triggers incorrect MIME type detection during access to an finfo object.`

Comment: This vulnerability also present in php 5.3?

Comment: yes till before 5.4.16.

Comment: Thank you! you should write an answer than i could accept it.

Comment: @Jumi No, as the CVE states: only PHP versions 5.4.x before 5.4.16 are vulnerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `fileinfo` has a security Vulnerability which can cause a Denial Of Service attack.

Quote from [cevdetails.com](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-4636/)

> The mget function in libmagic/softmagic.c in the Fileinfo component in
>   PHP 5.4.x before 5.4.16 allows remote attackers to cause a denial of
>   service (invalid pointer dereference and application crash) via an MP3
>   file that triggers incorrect MIME type detection during access to an
>   finfo object.

Comment: Soo has this been patched ?